# Delete not working in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using mysql. Following query is working in mysql browser but when I use this query in hibernate it gives me exception near inner select like:

```
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 104
```

This is giving error on second select clause.

Query is :

```
delete from table 
where columnA in (
  select columnA
  from (
      select columnA
      from table
      group by columnA
      having count(*) > 1
      ) t  
)
```

Do anyone have idea why this is so and how to resolve that?

Comment: what's this orphan 't' doing?

Comment: @Vihar Subquery alias

Comment: but unused, so orphan

Comment: @Vihar Some databases require an alias to be present even if not used, though I'm not sure about mysql

Comment: ohh I get it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your alias **'t'** is never used. Simply try this :)

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE columnA IN (SELECT columnA
      FROM table
      GROUP BY columnA
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

If you are dealing with Hibernate try to use Hibernate Query Language (HQL). For example, we use HQL to delete entities with more flexibility, such as removing products whose prices are greater than a specified amount.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete Product where price > :maxPrice");
query.setParameter("maxPrice", new Float(1000f));

int result = query.executeUpdate();

if (result > 0) {
    System.out.println("Expensive products was removed");
}
```

You can also use method execute(HibernateCallback action) from class **HibernateTemplate**. It could look like this:

```
final Criterion criteria;
HibernateTemplate template;
template.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    @Override
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        List toDelete = session.createCriteria(Student.class).add(criteria).list();
        for (Object o: toDelete){
            session.delete(o);
        }
    }
});
```

IMHO this solution is not very efficient, because you must read all entries before you remove them. What is more you must remove each entry individually, which is very unefficient.

Comment: it gives error like this : "You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Why do you use native SQL in Hibernate. Use Hibernates features instead:)

Comment: I am using hql query. I have converted it in hql but in hql it is not working.

Comment: can you share you DAOs for this case, please?

Comment: Sorry can't do that due to some privacy. If you want to know the datatype of columnA then it is string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105137/discussion-between-kostyan-sv-and-charvee-shah).